# Imgproc.copyMakeBorder in OpenCV 3.1?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, opencv3.1

I need  some methods of OpenCV Java 2.4.9 and 3.1, but 3.1 version `Imgproc` class has no `copyMakeBorder()` method, while it was present in version 2.4.9. Note that I can run them successfully if I only choose to add only one of them as library with some deficiencies.
So, is there a way that I can use them simultaneously?

Comment: Instead of using them together if it is possible then get the Source package of OpenCV 2.4.9 and copy that class and its dependency classes. Using OpenCV 2.4.9 and 3.1.1 would only create clash on classpath.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use OpenCV 3.1 only. `copyMakeBorder` has been moved to `Core`, and you can call it like:

```
int border = 2;
Core.copyMakeBorder(src, dst, border, border, border, border, Core.BORDER_REFLECT_101);
```